# iOS SDK 4.2 on Snow Leopard & XCode 3.2.6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I am trying to compile a code in XCODE but says it needs iOS SDK 4.2. XCODE installed 4.3. How do I resolve this problem? Is there a way to upgrade my code to 4.3, or download 4.2? I have Snow Leopard BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your base SDK to 4.3 in the Build Settings and you should be able to compile.

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem was that XCODE didn't get installed properly and was throwing exceptions left and right with 4.3.